# Common Collector Amplifier and its name

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Why is Common Collector amplifier is also known as Emitter Follower?

Comment: Because the voltage at the emitter "follows" the voltage at the base. Someone else can probably elaborate on this better though, so this is just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Try this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311637/understanding-common-terminal-in-common-collector-emitter-amplifier

Comment: It's just usage. There is a long-used "4-terminal network" analysis model. The BJT only has 3 terminals. Therefore one of the 3 terminals of the BJT must be connected to 2 of the terminals in the 4-terminal network model. Whichever of these it is, is the "common terminal" in the 4-terminal network model. So you can classify that way. In which case, it is a "common collector." However, if you think about how it acts in a circuit, then you very well might prefer to call it an "emitter follower." Different people choose to write differently. You need to be flexible, is all.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because the **collector** is **common** to the input (base/collector) and output (emitter/collector) current loops, whereas the emitter output signal **follows** the base input signal.

Answer (score 0):

**Emitter follower:** Perhaps you know an opamp based follower - a non-inverting opamp circuit with 100% negative feedback has unity gain. The theoretical background is a very large loop gain (identical to to the open-loop gain Aol of the opamp).

The same - or better: Nearly the same - applies to the common-collector circuit. A large emitter resistor RE provides nearly 100% negative feedback. Therefore, the gain between input node (base) and output node (emitter) is very close to unity - the emitter signal "follows " the input signal at the base node.

Here, the loop gain is Aol=gm*RE which is much greater than "1" for RE>>1/gm [gm: transconductance d(Ie)/d(Vbe)].